# Consul UI not able to load in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, consul, consul-kv

I need to use the CONSUL UI and due to some limitations i need to stick with the internet explorer.

I am not been successful to open the CONSUL UI in IE browser, whereas it is working perfectly fine in other browsers.

Error Produced in the console tab:

*index Unable to get property '**indexOf**' of undefined or null reference TypeError: Unable to get property '**indexOf**' of undefined or null reference*

Is there a way to get the CONSUL UI working in IE browser?[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure, whether it is fully compatible with the IE browser or not. I try to check the documentation but did not get any information about browser support. Do you see any error message in the console? Which version of the IE browser you are using? I also suggest you ask a question on the Consul forum to know their opinion on this error. https://discuss.hashicorp.com/c/consul

Comment: Thank you @Deepak-MSFT for your response. As suggested by you i have posted a question in the forum.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT The internet explorer version : 11.1098.17763.0

Comment: I am not sure about the cause of the issue. Let us know if you get any information from the consul UI thread. It may help to narrow down the issue. Here, I am attaching the link to it. So other users can also check it.  https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/not-being-able-to-launch-the-consul-ui-in-internet-explorer/7666